# Why does my SlidingTabLayout Restart my activity?

Tags: java, android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have 4 tabs, as shown below when I click from `Tags` to `Home` it restarts the `Home activity`. Why is that??

Also, my `slidingtabLayout` is a little choppy, does this have anything to do with the `home activity` restart?

```
   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //2 steps creating a fragment, create the fragment class and create the UI for it
        Fragment fragment = null;
        //we dont want it to return our place holder Fragment instead we want to switch bewtween 3
        //create a switch case based on the position applied or the fragment selected
        switch (position) {
            case HOME:
                fragment = Dashboard.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case TAGS:
                fragment = Tags.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case MY_RECENT:
                fragment = MyPosts.newInstance("","");
                break;
            case TOP;
                fragment = Top.newInstance("", "");
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Home";
            case 1:
                return "Top";
            case 2:
                return "Recent";
            case 3:
                return "Tags";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You post is a little unclear. Do you mean the hosting Activity restarts, or the home Fragment - which I'm assuming is the `Dashboard` Fragment - gets recreated?

Comment: Yes I meant that the dashboard fragment which is the home restarts when on fragment tags

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating a new instance of each fragment each time the user changes tab.  Also I think you should extend `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

If you create your Fragments in your `SectionsPagerAdapter` constructor, then keep a reference to them as member variables and then return a reference to your fragments in the `getItem()` method it should stop recreating fragments.

Maybe try something like this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

Fragment mDashboardFragment;
Fragment mTagsFragment;
Fragment mMyRecentFragment;
Fragment mTopFragment;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mHomeFragment = Dashboard.newInstance("",""); 
    mTagsFragment = Tags.newInstance("",""); 
    mMyRecentFragment= MyPosts.newInstance("",""); 
    mTopFragment = Top.newInstance("", "");

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    //create a switch case based on the position applied or the fragment selected
    switch (position) {
        case HOME:
            fragment = mDashboardFragment;
            break;
        case TAGS:
            fragment = mTagsFragment;
            break;
        case MY_RECENT:
            fragment = mMyRecentFragment;
            break;
        case TOP;
            fragment = mTopFragment;
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Home";
        case 1:
            return "Top";
        case 2:
            return "Recent";
        case 3:
            return "Tags";
    }
    return null;
}}}
```

Bear in mind that this could be quite inefficient as potentially creating fragments unnecessarily.

Comment: It still lags between tags and dashboard

Comment: Have you changed `extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Ya, it just goes blank

Comment: Do you mean it works but lags using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and with `FragmentPagerAdapter` it does not display the fragment at all?  Perhaps post your code for the `Dashboard` fragment as the issue could be in there.

Comment: If I use a fragmentStatePagerAdapter, the activity only restarts between tags and dashboard. When I use the FragmentPagerAdapter I get all the feeds of my tab fragments but when I cycle through until tags and then click on dashboard, it goes blank and the feed disappears.

Comment: Do you still think It might be an issue in my fragment dashboard?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  It does sound to me like a problem with the Dashboard Fragment.  You could verfiy by replacing with a different fragment and checking if your ViewPager displays all fragments correctly then.